# Opening email popups from Adobe AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, email, apache-flex, air

I need to open several email popups (~30) from Adobe AIR Flex app, I am currently using navigateToURL but I observed that at times some email popups go missing. I have tried callLater as well. WHen I introduce delay between popups it works better but still has a risk of some popup missing. Can anyone advise please? These emails dont have any attachments but have html contents.

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to do this?

Comment: There's a requirement for the user to view the email before he hits send. And by pressing one button he should be able to generate 25-30 emails (one email for each client of the user)

Comment: Would you not just create a script on the server that sends the email on the user's behalf?

Comment: user needs to view the email first and then will click on send button to send

Comment: So show the email body in your application and have a send button which sends the email?

Comment: hmm but there will be 30 popups from application and how can I have them outside the container?

Comment: You don't have 30 popups. You have one popup for each email type and generate the greeting server side or in your request to the server. What you want is terrible UX and likely is not doable due to limitations of other software. Not to mention you are entirely reliant on said software, rather than having control over it server-side. Worth noting that each different email software may have different limitations, as well, and if they use webmail, there could be spam security that could flag your application.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you don't want all 25-30 messages to appear at once. If you could try to schedule a better way like the one below, I think that will really help you fix the problem:-

1. Add references to all the 25-30 objects in an array
2. Now on click of a button, show the 1st email body. Have a button in the popup which reads something like 'Send and Read next email'. On click event, fire the email to be sent and pop the next object from your array to show contents of the next email.

Comment: no Vivek, the req is to have 25-30 emails to appear at once ofcourse the popups could come up in an interval of 2-3 seconds.